# Advice on working with current page in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to have your comment on what you think about the following.
I have a custom route that will resolve the current page and add it to RouteData object.
Imagine a controller with an Index method, which of these scenarios is preferable.
To take one parameter, current page as an argument to the index method or to have a property like this:

```
public Page CurrentPage { get { return RouteData.DataTokens ["CurrentPage"] as Page; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would prefer to have a controller action taking the `page` parameter. Makes the code more readable and easier to unit test. Just by looking at the action signature you know exactly on what parameters it depends.